# Library for data storage and analysis

Tags: c++, database, spreadsheet, analysis

So, I have this program that collects a bunch of interesting data. I want to have a library that I can use to sort this data into columns and rows (or similar), save it to a file, and then use some other program (like OpenOffice Spreadsheet, or MATLAB since I own it, or maybe some other spreadsheet/database grapher that I don't know of) to analyse and graph the data however I want. I prefer this library to be open source, but it's not really a requirement.

Comment: You want a library to write CSV files? Or you're looking for some kind of data model that fits what you have? In the latter case, we need to know more about its structure.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with CSV files, but they seem like they would work. Does MATLAB or similar support them?

Comment: Everything supports CSV. It's the lowest common denominator. Typically you just implement it without a library because it's so simple.

Comment: Oh, I see. It's funny I've never heard of it for so long... Well, if you make this an answer (maybe with a bit more explanation on how to read it in other programs) I'll accept it.

Comment: I'll leave that to someone else… who isn't feeling so guilty about doing SO at work…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so my mistake, you wanted a writer. Writing a CSV is simple and apparently reading them into matlab is simple too.

http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/ref/csvread.html

A CSV has a simple structure. For each row you seperate by newline. and each column is seperated by a comma.

> 0,10,15,12
>   4,7,0,3

So all you really need to do is grab your data, seperate it by rows then write a line out with each column seperated by a comma.

If you need a code example I can edit again but this shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: I don't want a parser, but a writer so it produces files compatible with MATLAB and/or other such software.

Comment: @myrkos you bet, it even can open them in proper format just by opening the file. You can also manually write a CSV in excel.